# When is "value !== value" ever true?

Tags: javascript

I'm researching object equality test functions and ran across this code in Lodash's "isEqual" function:

[https://bit.dev/lodash/lodash/internal/_base-is-equal/~code](https://bit.dev/lodash/lodash/internal/_base-is-equal/%7Ecode)

```js
function baseIsEqual(value, other, bitmask, customizer, stack) {
  if (value === other) {
    return true;
  }
  if (value == null || other == null || (!isObjectLike(value) && !isObjectLike(other))) {
    return value !== value && other !== other;
  }
  return baseIsEqualDeep(value, other, bitmask, customizer, baseIsEqual, stack);
}
```

**TLDR: When would `return value !== value && other !== other;` ever return true?**

The part that stumps me is the 2nd conditional and its return. Clearly the 1st condition catches simple strict equality cases. But, looking at the next test, I make the following observations (assumptions?):

- `value == null` is true only for 'null' and 'undefined'
- the "isObjectLike" clause eliminates anything not a primitive or a function

So, if the only values for `value` and `other` are primitives, undefined, null or functions, what values could satisfy the condition for a `true` return? Seeing this code in Lodash lends it credibility, so I'm also "assuming" it is legit ("assumptions"! ... yes, I know ... ).

Comment: When `value` is `NaN`, `value !== value` is `true`. `NaN` is the only value in JavaScript that has this particular feature (which comes to it from IEEE-754 floating point).

Comment: thanks ... forgot about NaN

Comment: So easy to do. :-D